# Properties of Chebyshev’s $\psi$ Function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

Given the definition $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$

How can one arrive to the conclusion below:

$$\psi(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\left\lfloor{\frac{\log x}{\log p}}\right\rfloor\log p $$

Comment: There are exactly $\lfloor \frac{\log x}{\log p}\rfloor$ powers of $p$ less than or equal than $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\lfloor\log x\over\log p\right\rfloor
&=\sum_{k\le\log x/\log p}1=\sum_{k\log p\le\log x}1 \\
&=\sum_{p^k\le x}1
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\psi(x)
&=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)=\sum_k\sum_{p^k\le x}\log p \\
&=\sum_{p\le x}\left\lfloor\log x\over\log p\right\rfloor\log p
\end{aligned}
$$